# MongoDB compass - Get the field name (key) with the max value, from 3 fields and their values in a document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-compass

I have this sample mongodb document -

```
{
    _id: 5db85ee97d9fb13ead4fc54c
    applId: 5d48f34f7d9fb10ce171f905
    fileId: "dd386cf7-4139-45c2-9853-cbb126621b51"
    job: Object
    country: "US"
    fullName: "abcd xyz"
    htmlWordCount: 2766
    textWordCount: 1867
    rchilliTextWordCount: 2840
    deleted: 0
    dateEntered: 2019-10-29 15:46:49.237
    dateModified: 2019-10-29 15:46:49.237
}
```

I want to build a query in compass so that I have following fields in the output -

```
{
    _id: 5db85ee97d9fb13ead4fc54c
    country: "US"
    fullName: "abcd xyz"
    htmlWordCount: 2766
    textWordCount: 1867
    rchilliTextWordCount: 2840
    winner: "rchilliTextWordCount"
}
```

Please note that it has a new field called "winner" which always returns the column with maximum wordcount (out of 3 `"htmlWordCount", "textWordCount", "rchilliTextWordCount"` columns). This new column `"winner"` is to be produced on runtime on query. Also this query is filtered on `country = "US"`.

How do I do this in MongoDB Compass or what should the aggregation pipeline look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [$switch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/) or [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      country: "US"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      country: 1,
      fullName: 1,
      htmlWordCount: 1,
      textWordCount: 1,
      rchilliTextWordCount: 1,
      winner: {
        $switch: {
          branches: [
            {
              case: {
                $and: [
                  {
                    $gt: [
                      "$htmlWordCount",
                      "$textWordCount"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    $gt: [
                      "$htmlWordCount",
                      "$rchilliTextWordCount"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              then: "htmlWordCount"
            },
            {
              case: {
                $and: [
                  {
                    $gt: [
                      "$textWordCount",
                      "$htmlWordCount"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    $gt: [
                      "$textWordCount",
                      "$rchilliTextWordCount"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              then: "textWordCount"
            },
            {
              case: {
                $and: [
                  {
                    $gt: [
                      "$rchilliTextWordCount",
                      "$htmlWordCount"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    $gt: [
                      "$rchilliTextWordCount",
                      "$textWordCount"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              then: "rchilliTextWordCount"
            }
          ],
          default: "No winners"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Jqe4nVC9iyD)

Answer (score 2):

This is another approach of getting the result:

1. Get the document's field names and their values
2. Find the maximum value for the fields with names in `[ "htmlWordCount", "textWordCount", "rchilliTextWordCount" ]`.

In general, finding a maximum value from an array is a kind of *reduction*; so I used the `$reduce` in this case. Note the code is simpler. In case you want add another field for calculating the maximum, just add it to the array.

```
db.winner.aggregate([
  { $match: { country: "US"} },
  { $addFields: { fieldNameValues: { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" } } },
  { $project: { _id: 1, country: 1, fullName: 1, htmlWordCount: 1, textWordCount: 1, rchilliTextWordCount: 1, 
                winner: { 
                    $reduce: {
                        input: "$fieldNameValues",
                        initialValue: { },
                        in: {
                            $cond: [
                               { $and: [ 
                                   { $in: [ "$$this.k", [ "htmlWordCount", "textWordCount", "rchilliTextWordCount" ] ] }, 
                                   { $gt: [ "$$this.v", "$$value.v"] } ]
                               },
                               "$$this",
                               "$$value"
                            ]
                        }
                    } 
               } 
  } },
  { $addFields: { winner: "$winner.k" } }
] )
```

---

**[ EDIT ADD ]**

**Sample Data and Result:**

```
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "fileId" : "dd386cf7-4139-45c2-9853-cbb126621b51",
        "job" : { },
        "country" : "US",
        "fullName" : "abcd xyz",
        "htmlWordCount" : 2766,
        "textWordCount" : 1867,
        "rchilliTextWordCount" : 2840
}
{
        "_id" : 2,
        "fileId" : "dd386cf7-4139-45c2-9853-cbb126621b51",
        "job" : { },
        "country" : "US",
        "fullName" : "lmn opqrs",
        "htmlWordCount" : 5,
        "textWordCount" : 9,
        "rchilliTextWordCount" : 2
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "country" : "US",
        "fullName" : "abcd xyz",
        "htmlWordCount" : 2766,
        "textWordCount" : 1867,
        "rchilliTextWordCount" : 2840,
        "winner" : "rchilliTextWordCount"
}
{
        "_id" : 2,
        "country" : "US",
        "fullName" : "lmn opqrs",
        "htmlWordCount" : 5,
        "textWordCount" : 9,
        "rchilliTextWordCount" : 2,
        "winner" : "textWordCount"
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works too. I guess this one is more efficient?

Comment: I can't say which is better with the available info. One can only tell when tried with some real data, scenarios where it is used, and from the point of maintenance and performance.